# Java how to select all instances of a class except one

Tags: java, class

I have 3 button objects of the same Class.
The class has a boolean variable 'on'.
I would like all other buttons to turn off when one is clicked.
For example, Pressing Button A sets its 'on' to true but all other instances of my button's 'on' turn to false.

Comment: Why not turn them **all** off and **then** turning on the one that was clicked?

Comment: Perhaps the following is appropriate? [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)